# Unable to assert span content properly with Selenium and pytest

Tags: selenium-webdriver, assert, pytest

I want to check if a span element contains a certain text. It normally contains more text than I search for.

That is what I do at the moment:

```
assert self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@id='cell_15_13']//span[@class='class_name']").get_attribute("innerHTML") == 'text'
```

I get the correct element with this code, but as I mentioned, the span contains more than my text, so my assertion fails.

Can somebody help me? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found it out myself.
That's what I did:

```
assert ("text") in self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@id='cell_15_13']//span[@class='class_name']").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `assert "text" in self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@id='cell_15_13']//span[@class='class_name']").text` to check if the text is present in the span element.

The `.text` attribute of the WebElement returns the text content of the element, including the text within its descendants. By using the in keyword, you can check if the text you're looking for is a substring of the element's text content.

This should give you the desired outcome.